# I can't see localhost of ubuntu server

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2

I am running Ubuntu server in virtualbox and in my host machine I try to view localhost in a browser and I see nothing. I have apache2 installed, what settings do I need to change to see my server in the browser of my host machine?

Comment: It's not clear (at least to me) whether your host and VM are sharing an IP address. Please [edit] your question to include your VM network settings.

Comment: `localhost` will show any servers running **on the host machine**. You need to type in the IP of the virtual machine.

Comment: read [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suppose that you install Apache on the virtual machine. So if you want to see the webpage of that Apache, you should do the following (easy way without having to configure routing stuff):

1.- With the VM halted, go to Settings (of the VM) > Network and in the adapter 1 choose

- Attached to "Bridged Adapter"
- Name: Let the default"
- Clic on "advanced"
- Promiscuous mode to: Allow All

2.- Turn on the VM

3.- When you log in the Ubuntu Server write:

```
ifconfig
```

Search something like:

```
192.168.x.x #Where "x" are numbers between 1 and 254
```

4.- Go to the browser on your host and type the address that you see on the step 3.